# What is the meaning of 'ld: library not found for -lm'

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, linker-errors, gfortran

I'm a beginner at Fortran code. I install gfortran from the homebrew to my apple silicon mac. The path show in the terminal when I type `which fortran` is `/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran`

I try to use bash shell to run a 'hello world' fortran file on the Desktop (.f90 file). I typed the following command in the terminal. `gfortran prog01_01.f90`. But it does not work. The error says: `ld: library not found for -lm` and `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. I have no idea how to deal with this problem.

Can anyone please help me this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the compiler cannot find the basic mathematical library `libm`. It should normally be included in your GLIBC or other standard C library installation and be available in the appropriate library directories and I would expect that your package manager would complain that something is missing.

Anyway, you simply have to fix your software installation, we cannot tell you more without details about your system and your software packages. You can try to install GLIBC if you did not install it yet.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I uninstall everything from my computer and install it using the way offered in https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases. And this problem is solved.